# Is there a way to select all rows correlated to the top ten groups in a database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to paginate a table while grouping the rows by a column.

I want to retrieve all correlated rows in the top ten unique groups.

ex. I have a column with countries. I want to select all rows related to the first ten unique countries. I am currently using GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and LIMIT to try to do it.

My current workaround is to grab the ten country names with one select statement, then run a second query to get all rows with those values, but there has to be a better way...

edit 1: example data and request
edit 2: reformatted data as a create table and insert statement to allow for easy reproduction as per suggestion in comment.

```
create table databaseName (  
country VARCHAR(100) not null,  
personName VARCHAR(200) not null,  
primary key (country)  
);

INSERT INTO databaseName(country, personName) VALUES
('USA', 'Bobby Green'),  
('USA', 'Jerry Smith'),  
('USA', 'Patrick Jones'),  
('Canada', 'Frank Green'),  
('Canada', 'Gary Smith'),  
('Canada', 'Hank Jones'),  
('Mexico', 'Hector Valdez'),  
('Mexico', 'Pedro Montoya'),  
('Mexico', 'Phil Gonzalez'),  
('Hungary', 'Ustef Granuchyk'),  
('Italy', 'Donatello Finici');
```

If I wanted all rows associated with the first two countries alphabetically I would get:

```
('Canada', 'Frank Green'),  
('Canada', 'Gary Smith'),  
('Canada', 'Hank Jones'),  
('Hungary', 'Ustef Granuchyk')
```

currently I use

```
SELECT * 
  FROM databaseName 
 GROUP 
    BY country 
 ORDER 
    BY country 
 LIMIT 0, 2
```

in this example I would get back Canada and Hungary, then I run a second query

```
SELECT *
  FROM databaseName 
 WHERE country IN ('Canada', 'Hungary');
```

I want to consolidate it into one query, not sure it is possible...

Edit: Resolution: Thanks to the answer below, I ended up using

```
SELECT databaseName.*  
 FROM  
 (SELECT DISTINCT country  
   FROM databaseName  
   LIMIT 0, 2  
   ) AS temp  
 LEFT JOIN databaseName  
   ON temp.country=databaseName.country  
 ORDER BY databaseName.country
```

It works great!

Comment: I'm still not quite clear on what you want to achieve.... Can you give some example data and show what you want as a result?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a temporary table with a selection (e.g. first 2 in alphabet) and left self join it.

```sql
SELECT databaseName.* 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM databaseName GROUP BY country ORDER BY country LIMIT 2
) AS temp 
LEFT JOIN databaseName ON temp.country=databaseName.country 
ORDER BY databaseName.country;
```